# Django: How to load form to current html page

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to load a form into my page without redirect to other pages.
I am using jquery. but nothing happens and I missing something very small I bet.
so.. I have a popup that I want the templete to load into.
my template that tries to show in my div:

**1) i dont know if i need to use the {% block content %}**

**EDIT: Yes i have to!**

**dayform.html** (templete)

```
{% block content %}

<form action="{% url 'dayform' %}" method='post'>
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}

<button name='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
path('calendar/dayform', views.addnewevent, name='dayform'),
```

**views.py**

```
 def addnewevent(request):
  if request.method != 'POST':
    form = Eventform()
  else:
    form = Eventform(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('controlpanel')

  context = {'form': form}
  return render(request, 'studentform/dayform.html', context)
```

**jquery**

```
$('.badge').get(
    "{% url 'dayform' %}",
    function(data) { $('#myform').html(data) }
);
```

the badge is  link clickable, I don't know if I should use "get" or "click"

Comment: What are your trying to achieve exactly? Where is the #badge in your template?

Comment: it dosent matter, when i click it , it run the func.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution:
in the js:
change to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.badge', function () {
    $.get(
        "{% url 'dayform' %}",
        function(data) { $('#myform').html(data) })

});
```